# Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path on android

Tags: android, retrofit

I'm using retrofit for getting my server data and fetch it to an ArrayList but here when I try to that I faced with that problem:

> Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path

I have received some other data from my server but this time (only this time) I have that problem soo guys plz help me.

Api.java

```
@POST("/Reclamation/get")
    @FormUrlEncoded
    Call<List<Reclamation>> getReclamationHistory(@Field("AgentSelector") String AgentSelector);
```

Reclamation Class:

```
public class Reclamation {
    private String CINAgent;
    private String GoogleLocation;
    private String longitude;
    private String lat;
    private String Rec_type;
    private String CINPerson;
    private String Rec_date;
    private String Rec_Description;
    private String Rec_infos;
    private String Person_Name;
    private String Agent_Name;

    public Reclamation(String CINAgent, String googleLocation, String longitude, String lat, String rec_type, String CINPerson, String rec_date, String rec_Description, String rec_infos, String person_Name, String agent_Name) {
        this.CINAgent = CINAgent;
        GoogleLocation = googleLocation;
        this.longitude = longitude;
        this.lat = lat;
        Rec_type = rec_type;
        this.CINPerson = CINPerson;
        Rec_date = rec_date;
        Rec_Description = rec_Description;
        Rec_infos = rec_infos;
        Person_Name = person_Name;
        Agent_Name = agent_Name;
    }

    public String getCINAgent() {
        return CINAgent;
    }

    public void setCINAgent(String CINAgent) {
        this.CINAgent = CINAgent;
    }

    public String getGoogleLocation() {
        return GoogleLocation;
    }

    public void setGoogleLocation(String googleLocation) {
        GoogleLocation = googleLocation;
    }

    public String getLongitude() {
        return longitude;
    }

    public void setLongitude(String longitude) {
        this.longitude = longitude;
    }

    public String getLat() {
        return lat;
    }

    public void setLat(String lat) {
        this.lat = lat;
    }

    public String getRec_type() {
        return Rec_type;
    }

    public void setRec_type(String rec_type) {
        Rec_type = rec_type;
    }

    public String getCINPerson() {
        return CINPerson;
    }

    public void setCINPerson(String CINPerson) {
        this.CINPerson = CINPerson;
    }

    public String getRec_date() {
        return Rec_date;
    }

    public void setRec_date(String rec_date) {
        Rec_date = rec_date;
    }

    public String getRec_Description() {
        return Rec_Description;
    }

    public void setRec_Description(String rec_Description) {
        Rec_Description = rec_Description;
    }

    public String getRec_infos() {
        return Rec_infos;
    }

    public void setRec_infos(String rec_infos) {
        Rec_infos = rec_infos;
    }

    public String getPerson_Name() {
        return Person_Name;
    }

    public void setPerson_Name(String person_Name) {
        Person_Name = person_Name;
    }

    public String getAgent_Name() {
        return Agent_Name;
    }

    public void setAgent_Name(String agent_Name) {
        Agent_Name = agent_Name;
    }
}
```

and My activity:

```
private void getReclamation(String selector) {
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(Api.BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()) //Here we are using the GsonConverterFactory to directly convert json data to object
                .build();

        Api api = retrofit.create(Api.class);

        Call<List<Reclamation>> call = api.getReclamationHistory(selector);

        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Reclamation>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<Reclamation>> call, Response<List<Reclamation>> response) {
                List<Reclamation> colList = response.body();
                for (Reclamation c : colList) {
                    Log.d("RFIDcode : ", c.getAgent_Name() + "");
                    ReclamationList.add(new Reclamation(c.getCINAgent(), c.getGoogleLocation(), c.getLongitude(), c.getLat(), c.getRec_type(), c.getCINPerson(), c.getRec_date(), c.getRec_Description(), c.getRec_infos(), c.getPerson_Name(), c.getAgent_Name()));
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<Reclamation>> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.d("RFIDcode : ", "error"+ t.getMessage());
            }
        });
    }
```

the respance data like :

```
[{
    _id: 5ee0a1a6aec0c900172a81e9,
    CINAgent: '12010057',
     GoogleLocation: 'https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query=36.8362243,10.2024426',
     longitude: '10.2024426',
     lat: '36.8362243',
     Rec_type: 'Dépassement de vitesse',
    CINPerson: '13010087',
     Rec_date: '10/06/2020 at 10:02:29 ',
    Rec_Description: '',
     Rec_infos: '',
    Person_Name: 'Bouhajja alaeddine',
     Agent_Name: 'Sami Akirmi'
   },
   {
     _id: 5ee0a65ac3f6d200175c7d82,
     CINAgent: '12010057',
    GoogleLocation: 'https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query=36.8362243,10.2024426',
     longitude: '10.2024426',
     lat: '36.8362243',
    Rec_type: 'Dépassement de vitesse',
     CINPerson: '13010087',
     Rec_date: '10/06/2020 at 10:22:33 ',
    Rec_Description: '',
     Rec_infos: '',
    Person_Name: 'Bouhajja alaeddine',
    Agent_Name: 'Sami Akirmi'
   }
 ]
```

Comment: That error means the response data which is json, is an object not a list eg. Ur data starts with { , not {[  that you expected. Pls post your raw response pls

Comment: ok two mins and will post it

Comment: Ok very thanks it is solved now, I found when I return to my server that I use find without casting the result to array so It will send an Json list to my device not an object

Comment: Okay. Happy to have helped